# How to trace a SQL query back to BO user who issued it

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, crystal-reports, business-objects

We have a Oracle 11g database and Business Objects user use this for reporting. 
We have identified queries that takes longest time to execute using Oracle DBA_HIST tables and found that theses are the queries issued by Web Intelligence or Crystal reports. Now we want to trace these queries back to the BO user who issued them. Oracle only gives the schema name which issued the query. I know we can use BO audit tables to track the user within BO but how to match Oracle DBA_HIST data to BO audit tables data. Or is there an another way of doing this?

Most of the crystal reports user query the database directly with their own queries without any universe, so use of END_SQL function to add the BO user name as a comment to all SQL statements is not possible.

Thanks fro the help.

Comment: Have you looked at V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY?  It will let you see activity for a time range and tie that to a specific machine and port.  SQL_ID is also provided so you can look for specific queries.

Comment: For completing Stilgar answer, be careful V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY is part of the diagnostic pack you need to have a license to query this view. it's the best way to investigate a problem afterwards, use it if you can.

Comment: Thanks guys. My problem is I want to trace that SQL_ID back to the Business objects user who issued the query. As business object user connect through a schema, oracle only gives me the ID of that schema.

Comment: All right, it connects to a schema, but is he connecting from an application on his workstation? if yes, you can have a look at the "machine" column and you can see it's workstation.
If he goes through an application server with a shared schema you have no way to know.

Comment: Thanks. user goes through a application server using a shared schema.